# Tensorflow importing issue mac

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, deep-learning

I followed the instruction as

```
              https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/get_started/os_setup.html#on-macosx
```

for mac installation.

After installation I navigate to python and tried to import Tensorflow and got following problems.

```
   (tensorflow) min:~ min$ python
   Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37)  
   [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on    darwin
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> import tensorflow as tf
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/Users/codeback/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
   from tensorflow.python import *
   File "/Users/codeback/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
   import ctypes
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
  from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
  ImportError: dlopen(/Users/codeback/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/lib-   dynload/_ctypes.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyInt_AsInt
 Referenced from: /Users/codeback/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
   Expected in: flat namespace
  in /Users/codeback/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
```

guys I'm new to installing tensorflow. so I need detail explanation 
thank you

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue with pyenv. Following [these instructions](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1753#issuecomment-195987865) should clear things up.

> Reverting the change to pyenv will get existing built extension modules working again, but won't solve the problem the pyenv change was intended to address: binary compatibility with prebuilt Mac OS X and manylinux1 wheel files published to PyPI.
>
> On Linux, the following command will rebuild all of the modules in an environment (don't run it directly against your system Python!):
> `$ pip freeze | pip install --ignore-installed --no-use-wheel -r /dev/stdin`

Comment: hi, thx but im quite new to this. so i just put  $ pip freeze | pip install --ignore-installed --no-use-wheel -r /dev/stdin commend on my mac terminal? please give me the specific direction

Comment: `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Then

`pip install --ignore-installed --no-use-wheel -r requirements.txt`

Comment: $ pip install --ignore-installed --no-use-wheel -r requirements.txt
DEPRECATION: --no-use-wheel is deprecated and will be removed in the future.  Please use --no-binary :all: instead.
Collecting alabaster==0.7.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached alabaster-0.7.7.tar.gz
Collecting anaconda-client==1.4.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))

Comment: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anaconda-client==1.4.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: 1.1.1, 1.2.2)
No matching distribution found for anaconda-client==1.4.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))

Comment: @sayuri does the exact same error still occur? Have you tried finding the correct version of anaconda-client and attempting the install again?